# How to convert Json file to CSV in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I would like to convert below Json file  to CSV file by using python.
Please don't pass the whole json data in the code. Just pass the whole Json file in the code.

```
{
  "Breakfast": {
    "Brk_item1": "Milk",
    "Brk_item2": "Egg"
  },
  "Lunch": {
    "Lnc_item1": "Pasta",
    "Lnc_item2": "Sprouts"
  },
  "Dinner": {
    "Dnr_item1": "Pizza",
    "Dnr_item2": "Burger"
  }
},

{
  "Breakfast": {
    "Brk_item1": "Bread",
    "Brk_item2": "Butter"
  },
  "Lunch": {
    "Lnc_item1": "Indian Meal",
    "Lnc_item2": "Paratha"
  },
  "Dinner": {
    "Dnr_item1": "Roti",
    "Dnr_item2": "Paneer"
  }
}
```

and my expected output will be like below in CSV format

```
Brk_item1   Brk_item2   Lnc_item1   Lnc_item2   Dnr_item1   Dnr_item2

Milk        Egg         Pasta       Sprouts     Pizza       Burger

Bread       Butter      Indian Meal Paratha     Roti        Paneer
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
import json
import csv
with open("./sample.json") as file:
  data = json.load(file)

fname="output.csv"

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow ([ "Brk_item1","Brk_item2","Lnc_item1","Lnc_item2","Dnr_item1","Dnr_item2"])
    for item in data["Breakfast"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item["Brk_item1"],item["Brk_item2"],item["Lnc_item1"],item["Lnc_item2"],item["Dnr_item1"],item["Dnr_item2"]])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and read [ask]. Have you pasted your question's title into a search engine? Have you tried anything? We're not here to write code for you, and you're expected to make an effort yourself.

Comment: is your json an array of objects or one object? Its best to work with a list of single-level objects when converting to flat csv files

Comment: My json is array of objects

Comment: Is your json being generated by another system or is it being manually created? It would be a bit easier if it was an array of objects `[]` at root node, rather than an object with `{}` at root node and keys for each "row". I would make each "row" a separate object inside of an array with a name field like: `"name": "Breakfast"` rather than a key, but its still possible in this format. Also your json is invalid because it has more than one root node (as posted in your question)

Comment: I receive my json from upstream database. I just mocked up the data with the existing structure.

Comment: so are those two objects above two different json files?

Comment: No both of these objects are in same json file.

Comment: ok, so are they in a json array at the root?

Comment: No arrays and this is how i receive json file from upstream

Comment: the json posted above errors because there are two json objects at the root

Comment: The headers are always the same? All objects have 3 dict elements "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"? And the sons of these elements are always 2? This is important to explain

Comment: @JoãoCastilho yes. Headers are always same and objects have 3 dictionary element and the sons of these elements are always 2

Answer (score 0):

The first step is writting the header of file (you did it correctly).

```
csv_file = csv.writer(file)
csv_file.writerow (["Brk_item1","Brk_item2","Lnc_item1","Lnc_item2","Dnr_item1","Dnr_item2"])
```

If your loaded json array, it's an array of dicts, the next step is iterate the array elements `for elem in data`. So, in this step, each elem is a dict which has 3 elements: `Breakfast`, `Lunch`, `Dinner`.
There all multiple ways to append the values, but as the element names of dicts are all different, and just are 3 elements and they are always the same, the easy way is to hardcode the values.

```
fname="output.csv"

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow (["Brk_item1","Brk_item2","Lnc_item1","Lnc_item2","Dnr_item1","Dnr_item2"])
    for elem in data:
        csv_file.writerow([elem['Breakfast']['Brk_item1'],elem['Breakfast']['Brk_item2'],elem['Lunch']['Lnc_item1'], elem['Lunch']['Lnc_item2'], elem['Dinner']['Dnr_item1'],elem['Dinner']['Dnr_item2']])
```

Comment: I am getting below error after implemented the above logic  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 12, in <module>
    csv_file.writerow([elem['Breakfast']['Brk_item1'],elem['Breakfast']['Brk_item2'],elem['Lunch']['Lnc_item1'], elem['Lunch']['Lnc_item2'], elem['Dinner']['Dnr_item1'],elem['Dinner']['Dnr_item2']])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: How is represented your data variable?